# Show series function is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I have a series

$$\sum ^\infty _{n=1} \sin{\left(\frac{x}{n^4}\right)} \cos{(nx)}, \quad \text{for } x \in \mathbb{R}$$

At first I had to show that the series is absolutely convergent on $\mathbb{R}$, I did so using that $|\sin (a)| \leq |a|$ and then arriving at:

$$|x|\sum^\infty _{n=1} \left|\frac{1}{n^4}\right|$$

to show that the series is absolutely convergent on $\mathbb{R}$. However now I have to show that the function series

$$f(x) = \sum ^\infty _{n=1} \sin{\left(\frac{x}{n^4}\right)} \cos{(nx)}, \quad \text{for } x \in \mathbb{R}$$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$.

So I'm thinking I need to show that it is uniformly convergent, and I think I need to use the previous result to do that, possibly by finding a convergent majorant series, but it's not obvious to me how I'd go about doing that.

Sorry if a similar question has been asked before, I wasnt able to find one.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Weierstrass' test, from your previous estimate you see that the series is totally (hence uniformly) convergent on any bounded interval $[-a,a]$.
Since it is the sum of continous functions, the sum $f$ is then continuous on every interval $[-a,a]$, hence on all $\mathbb{R}$.

(To prove the continuity of $f$ on a given point $x_0\in\mathbb{R}$ it is enough to pick $a > |x_0|$.)

Comment: Can you expand on why exactly the series is uniformly convergent on $[-a, a]$? I'm not entirely sure how absolute convergence gets us to uniform convergence in this case.

Comment: You have to use Weierstrass' M-test: since $|f_n(x)| \leq a/n^4 =: M_n$ for every $x\in [-a,a]$, and $\sum M_n$ is convergent, then $\sum f_n(x)$ is uniformly convergent in $[-a,a]$.

Comment: Ah, I assumed that would be choosing an $M_n$ dependent on $x$, but I see now that since it uses the bounds then it doesn't really depend on $x$. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If you restrict the series to a compact interval, say $[-N,N],$ you see with your inequality that the series is uniformly convergent on this interval, and thus converges to a continuous function. As you can choose your interval as large as you wish, you have your desired result.